# How i can make onclick to start animation

Tags: javascript

I got `requestAnimationFrame(loop);` and I'm trying to make onclick button to start animation, once you press it animation starts, I got button figured out `<button type="start" form="form1" value="start onclick="start()">start</button>` 
But i cannot figure out how to make it into a script.

Comment: Please add your html and js code.

Comment: `start` is not a valid value for the `type` attribute

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a snippet example :

```
<button onclick="start()">start</button>
<script>
   var animId=false;
   function start() {
      animId=requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
   function loop() {
      //your code here
   }
   // I added this in case you wanted to call a stop
   function stop() {
      animId && cancelAnimationFrame(animId);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `requestAnimationFrame(loop)` you should do it like this...

```
<button type="start" form="form1" value="start" onclick="requestAnimationFrame(loop)">start</button>
```